# Are there any opensource Django projects that exclusively use class based views?

Tags: django, open-source, django-class-based-views

I want to get a better feel for class based views and see how they're used in real projects. I'm looking for projects that are exclusively built using class-based-views or at least have a significant use of class-based-views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [source code of open knesset](https://github.com/ofri/Open-Knesset) (Israeli website about the [Knesset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knesset) - not the official)

Comment: Thanks for the link...I just cloned the project and will be going through it thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

ye here is my opensource project which all used class-based view. that is a blog system named UUBlog.
git:https://github.com/djangochina/UUBlog/

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**